# Full path between two nodes cyclic structure pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have an input data which consists of ID,prev,current and next node (not sorted).
I have to find a path between the first and last page for each ID which covers all the nodes traversed.
for eg : if my input data is like :
first column is ID, second column is prev_node, third column is current node, fourth column is next node.
Prev_node will be empty for starting value and next node will be empty for last value

*input*

```
id  prev  current  next     
------------------------
1    a      b       c  
1    a      e       f  
1    a      b       g  
1    a      b       o    
1    b      c       d  
1    b      g       h  
1    b      o       p  
1    c      d       a  
1    c      b       g  
1    d      a       e  
1    e      f       e  
1    e      f       f  
1    f      e       f  
1    f      f       f  
1    f      f       a  
1    f      a       b  
1    g      h       i  
1    h      i       j   
1    h      j       i  
1    i      j       i  
1    i      i       k  
1    i      k       l  
1    j      i       i  
1    k      l       m  
1    l      m       n  
1    l      n       a  
1    m      n       a  
1    n      a       b  
1    o      p       q  
1    p      q       r  
1    q      r       s  
1    r      s       t  
1    s      t       u  
1    t      u       v  
1    u      v       w  
1    v      w       x  
1    w      x         
1           a       b
```

*output* should be the path of current node like -

```
ID    current  
-------------
1       a  
1       b  
1       c  
1       d  
1       a  
1       e  
1       f  
1       e  
1       f  
1       f  
1       f  
1      a  
1      b  
1      b  
1      g  
1      h  
1      i  
1      j  
1      j  
1      i  
1      i   
1      k  
1      l  
1      m  
1      n  
1      n  
1      a  
1      b  
1      o  
1      p  
1      q  
1      r  
1      s  
1      t  
1      u  
1     v  
1      w  
1      x
```

There will be many IDs with similar data here. I have shown only one ID(1). Also here i have used alphabets which will actually be 200-500 character long string. I tried the SQL approach with little modification, it works fine if an ID has 100 or below rows but gives string concatenation error for more rows (even after converting the long strings to number). Can anyone please suggest a robust procedure based approach to same. I tried some but it doesn't work for more than 300 rows for a ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with 
  t_n as (
    select prev, curr, next, rownum n from your_table
  ),
  t_br as (
    select prev, curr, 
      '<'||listagg(n, '|<')within group(order by n)||'|' br,
      count(0) cnt
    from t_n
    group by prev, curr
  ),
  t_mp as (
    select 
      '|'||listagg(list)within group(order by null) list
    from (
      select replace(br, '<') list
      from t_br
      where cnt > 1
    )
  ),
  t_path(step, curr, next, used) as (
    select 1, curr, next, ''
    from t_n where prev is null
    union all
    select step + 1, t_br.curr, t_n.next, 
      case when instr(list, '|'||n||'|') = 0 then used
      else used||n||'|' end
    from t_mp, t_path
    join t_br 
      on next = t_br.curr and t_path.curr = prev
    join t_n 
      on n = regexp_substr(br,'^(<('||used||'0)\|)*(<(\d+))?',1,1,'',4)
  ) cycle step set is_cycle to 'Y' default 'N'
select step, curr from t_path order by 1;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24866/1)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i think one loop is missed using this code. eg : there are 3 a,b in the input but in the output am getting only two a,b. Can you please help me regarding why this might be happening?

Comment: @user2342436 - There are 3 a,b in the output (steps 1, 12, 24)

Comment: thanks a lot Egor. Great help!! Will test the query with all conditions.

Comment: Am facing this error :ORA-01489 result of string concatenation is too long. Can you please help me with a work around on this

Comment: @user2342436 - This solution is in pure SQL.  SQL strings are limited to 4000 bytes.  You should use PL/SQL to work with long strings or collections.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Really appreciate it

Comment: Hi Egor !! I have converted the above code to pl/sql. My code supplies values(page_id,prev_pg,next_pg) for each Identifier.The problem am facing now is sometimes the identifier path(page_id,prev_pg,next_pg) loops infinitely cause of data issues. Can i put an exception block or something to remove those and continue with other records?

Comment: @user2342436 - Please open new question and post your PL/SQL code.